# C: POST json request using sockets returns 400 bad request

Tags: c, sockets

I got the raw request from Python using request logging, where the status is 200:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int sockfd;
    char buf[2056];
    int byte_count;
    memset(&hints, 0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getaddrinfo("example.com","443", &hints, &res);
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    printf("Connecting...\n");
    connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);
    printf("Connected!\n");
    char *header = "POST /abc HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 22\r\n\r\n{\"abcdeghiewf\": \"abc\"}";
    send(sockfd,header,strlen(header),0);
    printf("POST Sent...\n");
    byte_count = recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
    printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n",byte_count);
    printf("%.*s",byte_count,buf);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the request I get from Python's requests module:

```
send: b'POST /abc HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 22\r\n\r\n'

send: b'{"abcdeghiewf": "abc"}'
```

Comment: On a side note, there is no error handling whatsoever in this code. Any of the functions are you calling could fail, which you are not checking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to port 443, which is the default HTTPS TLS port. But you are not negotiating a TLS handshake to establish an encrypted session before then exchanging HTTP messages inside that session.

The server is detected an un-encrypted HTTP message on a port that requires encryption, so it is sending an un-encrypted response back, and likely ending the connection.

So, you need to either:

- connect to port 80 instead of 443
- implement TLS properly, such as by using OpenSSL or any other similar encryption library/API.

Comment: I tried using openssl but i did not really get it, could you provide me a simple example to do so? Thanks

Comment: @kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk there are plenty of online tutorials, even whole books, on how to use OpenSSL